# How to show land area into gridview by converting into a common unit

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple form in Asp.Net(C#) in which user enters his details. The detail includes the total land area of the user and its unit(hectare,meter,feet etc). This detail is saved into Sql database. This detail should be shown in a gridview. I have done upto this but my problem is that the land area is to be shown in a common unit(hectare). The restriction is that it should be converted while getting the submitted data from Database. Do anyone have solution for it.

Comment: Share your code and tell people what you have tried..

Comment: I am simply getting the data from database and showing it into gridview by a simple stored procedure. But i dont know how to apply the logic to convert the area into a specific unit to show in GridView.

Comment: That's simple multiplication or division. You can do this in SQL select ad hoc or using a stored procedure or you can do this in C# before filling the grid view. So where is the actual problem? How do you fill the data? How do you get the data? Linq to SQL, Linq to Entities, bare Ado.NET?

Comment: i am using Ado.Net and the stored procedure data is stored into datatable and then binded to gridview @CSharper

Answer (score 1):

The easy options for your scenario are:

- create a computed column directly on the database if your db system supports them (e.g. SQL Server does) and return it from the stored procedure
- modify the stored procedure for fetching the data so it does the transformation (e.g. with a case statement in SQL Server

  case t.unit
      when 'hectare' then t.area
      when 'sqmeter' then t.area / 10000
      when 'sqfeet' then t.area / xxxx
  end
- add a column to the data table and calculate the value before binding the data (data tables can also have computed columns but the formula syntax is quite limited so it seems to be better to do it manually in C#)

  table.Columns.Add("AreaInHectare");
  foreach (var row in table) {
      row["AreaInHectare"] = GetAreaInHectare((decimal)row["Area"], (string)row["Unit"];
  }

Most probably you will like to apply some rounding also to cut off unneeded decimal places.

Comment: thnx for the answer let me try that